# Why is one of the two variables undefined?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

After doing an asynchronous call, one of values of the response object keeps undefined.

I'm creating a little rest api with express and mongodb (mongoose). I'm stucked with this async call:

```
app.get('/stuff/:explotacio', async (req,res) =>{
  const myExplotacio = await Explotacio.findById(req.params.explotacio);  
  console.log('explotacio ',myExplotacio);     
  const {lat,lon} = myExplotacio;
  console.log('lon',lon);  
  const processed = doOtherStuff(lat,lon);
  res.send(processed);
}
```

The value of myExplotacio console.log is this:

```
expotacio { parceles: [],
                _id: 5c2fa88b1c9d440000d3e970,
                 lat: 41.931433,
                 lon: 2.250807,
                 nom: 'casa' }
```

The value of the lon console.log is

```
lon undefined
```

The esquema for explotacio is this one:

```
const ExplotacioSchema = new Schema({
  nom:{
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  long:{
      type:Number
  },
  lat:{
      type:Number
  },
  parceles:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:"Parcela"}]
});
```

what's driving me mad is that "lat" has a value but "lon" keeps undefined. When console.log(myExplotacio) i can see value for both lat and lon!!

Comment: Maybe you should add the value of `myExplotacio` to the question. It's hard to do anything other than guess without knowing that.

Comment: Sure, sorry, I forgot it.

Comment: Where in your program is the value of `lon` showing `undefined`? I wonder what your `doOtherStuff` function returns...

Comment: I'm doing console.log just before `doOtherStuff` and getting `undefined`. the error that's giving the `doOtherSuff` function is because the `undefined`of lon. It makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: What does the schema for `Explotacio` look like?

Comment: Does it have a `long` property or a `lon`

Comment: F me, thank you. Couldn't see this.

Comment: As @MarkMeyer stated, your schema uses `long` and not `lon` although I am uncertain as to how your log shows `lon` unless that wasn't a copy/paste.

Comment: It was a copy/paste. I guess it shows lon because I created the example document directly to the DB with the Mongodb Compass app. Not through the api